# What is the "canary thread" and why is it starving?

Tags: 11.04, log

The following occasionally appears in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
rtkit-daemon[1145]: The canary thread is apparently starving. Taking action.
rtkit-daemon[1145]: Demoting known real-time threads.
rtkit-daemon[1145]: Successfully demoted thread 1431 of process 1368 (n/a).
rtkit-daemon[1145]: Successfully demoted thread 1430 of process 1368 (n/a).
rtkit-daemon[1145]: Successfully demoted thread 1368 of process 1368 (n/a).
rtkit-daemon[1145]: Demoted 3 threads.
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Any errors in kern.log concerning ACPI? If so: enter BIOS and check if `ACPI power save options` is set to `Extended`. Change it to `Normal`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The term "canary" as used here comes from [coal mining](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/canary_in_a_coal_mine) originally.  Coal miners used canaries to detect dangerous gases (if the canary they carried with them died, they knew they had to get out of the shaft/mine ASAP).  As a result the term "canary" is now often used for anything that you use to get an (early) warning about a dangerous situation.

In this case it [seems](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/precise/rtkit/precise/view/head:/README#L39) like 'rtkit' starts a "normal" thread to test if the threads that get "real time" priorities are "starving" other threads (& processes), where "starving" means that they get too little processor time.  This is a safety measure to make sure that processes/threads that have access to real time priorities don't use up so much CPU time that other tasks get none anymore.

So apparently some thread(s) that got real-time priorities from rtkit is/are misbehaving, and trying to monopolize the CPU, rtkit detects this with its "canary thread", and thus rtkit takes away the real-time priorities.

Answer (score -3):

It is a buffer overflow

[Wikipedia buffer overflow canaries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow_protection#Canaries)

I can not tell from the logs you posted where the problem is, can you check or pastebin log entries above an below those messages ? What is process 1368 ?

```
sudo ps -p 1368
```

Comment: This is not about buffer overflows, but the use of the word "canary" there is also derived from the use of coal miner's canaries.