systemd-sleep: Failed to put system to sleep. System resumed again: Device or resource busy
Suddenly, putting system to sleep started failing, here is the entire /var/log/syslog https://gist.github.com/umpirsky/f3e1a8d32217ad4b8fb3186124866d69
I disabled all entries in /proc/acpi/wakeup, it didn't help.
Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Any idea why this started happening? Thanks.

What is the version of Ubuntu?

'The canary thread is apparently starving' See https://askubuntu.com/questions/86974/what-is-the-canary-thread-and-why-is-it-starving as a starting point. What other processes are you running?

@DavidDE Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

@david See https://gist.github.com/umpirsky/f32795b0d370b48e74f8d6ef9f98d11c

@umpirsky I couldn't see anything that really stands out, however, you should add the new information to your original question. I did notice that you have twice the number of processes running than I do but I wouldn't say excessive. (I am no expert.) The processes that stands out are TILIX & PLEX as they are non-ubuntu ones. Does the sleep/suspend cause the same problem if these aren't running?

@david Yes, the issue persists when I kill plex and tilix. Thanks.

@umpirsky The cause of the staving canary was 'Freezing of tasks failed after 20.010 seconds' and you have 9 tasks that are not complying. Take a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1346908/suspend-freezing-of-tasks-failed-after-20-seconds and see if this sheds some light on things.

Thanks @david. I tried increasing timeout to 60s, but it still fails Freezing of tasks failed after 60.002 seconds. Unfortunatelly I can't identify what tasks are causing issues, I can only guess it's some driver. I will try to disconnect some devices...

@umpirsky What does dmesg report? I notice 'sunrpc' is mentioned in the log for the failing processes.  https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oracular/en/man5/proc_sys_sunrpc.5.html

@david Here is the output https://gist.github.com/umpirsky/c63decef73efe3bd6498d93b5e6a522a. I tried disconnecting usb devices, the issue persisted.

The cause of system sleep failing may be a recent kernel update.
To check:

Restart your system.
If you don't see the GRUB menu hold Shift while booting.
In the GRUB menu choose Advanced Options for Ubuntu.
Choose the second generic kernel, which is a previous version of the kernel had installed.
Let it start and check your sleep mode. If it works, try the answer from @rishuverma to the question Set "older" kernel as default grub entry to make GRUB to load the older kernel automatically (I'm making the rest specific to the linux-modules-5.15.0-117-generic kernel as you've confirmed that this older kernel worked for you).

To not have the working, older kernel be deleted after an update:

Install Synaptic Package manager:
sudo apt install synaptic


Start Synaptic.

Go to Status, Installed (manual) and make sure you do not see linux-modules-5.15.0-117-generic.

Go to Status, Installed and find linux-modules-5.15.0-117-generic.

Mark the package, click the Package menu on top of page and remove the check from Automatically installed:


Check the package in Status, Installed (manual).



Switching form 5.15.0-118-generic to 5.15.0-117-generic fixed the issue, thanks!

Is this bug reported/fixed somewhere?

I do not think so, do you need the info to make 5.15-0-117, so that it won't be deleted?

I see 3 versions now 5.15.0-118-generic, 5.15.0-117-generic and 5.4.0-125-generic. anything that keeps 5.15.0-117-generic in the list is welcome, thanks.

Just come back in one day and see if anything changed.

This bug has been noticed and fixed/committed to 5.15.0-121.131 Not sure when that will appear in regular updates, but see here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2076576

If you don't want to look into kernel changes, I found that this answer to a similar question solved the problem for me.
Copying here:

I enabled hibernation some month ago in my Ubuntu system, now 20.04, but now as in the past I had some issue.
So in this last event I found this in "dmsg" during hibernation procedure:

 Freezing of tasks failed after 20.005 seconds (0 tasks refusing to freeze, wq_busy=1)...

I solved with increasing the freezing timeout from 20 sec to 30 sec:

echo 30000 > /sys/power/pm_freeze_timeout

and made I it permanent with sysfsutils and after writing

power/pm_freeze_timeout = 30000

in a file in the /etc/sysfs.d directory

