Ubuntu 22.04: Suspend, hibernate, and shutdown fail in different ways
Specs
Laptop - Lenovo Thinkpad X260
OS - Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Overview
I use suspend at least a couple times daily, and noticed an issue with it two days ago where suspend fails and I can only reboot.
As I was trying to figure it out, I noticed similar issues with hibernate and shutdown (though I use hibernate and shutdown rarely, so it's unclear whether these problems are really related or not, and when hibernate and shutdown stopped working).
In each case, the symptoms are slightly different, as described below.
I'll be referring to an "audio tick", this is a small static tick that sounds like a static shock and that I could hear when wearing earphones when the laptop suspends, hibernates, or turns off successfully.
I don't know exactly what was causing it (always just assumed the audio server turning off), but it has always been a consistent signal than the laptop was done and I could put it away.
Issue Descriptions
Suspend
Trigger - Problem appears when I close the lid (which triggers suspension) or by running sudo pm-suspend
Expectation - Laptop should take a second to suspend, the screen should turn black, then I should hear the audio tick, and I can put the laptop away. Later, I should open the lid and everything goes back to running as normal.
What actually happens - Laptop takes a second to suspend, the screen goes black (but it looks still like the screen is on, just black), I never hear the audio tick, and then nothing happens. The laptop stays in this unresponsive state indefinitely until I power it off manually.
Log of sudo journalctl -S today (cut from the moment I run pm-suspend until the time I manually reboot, which happens just a couple of lines underneath, so not much to look at): https://pastebin.com/uDf2Yein
Hibernate
Trigger - Problem appears when I run sudo pm-hibernate
Expectation - Laptop should take a few seconds to hibernate, the screen should turn black, then I should hear the audio tick, and I can put the laptop away. Later, I should open the lid (maybe I also need to press the power button to wake from hibernation, don't remember) and everything goes back to running as normal.
What actually happens - Laptop takes a few secons to hibernate, the screen turns black, I don't hear the audio tick, the screen goes back on, and everything goes back to running as if nothing had happened.
What I tried
Full log of sudo journalctl -S today (cut from the moment I run pm-hibernate): https://pastebin.com/kLYymK7T
There is a segment about the swapfile that seems relevant (shown below), but I could not figure why those logs are there, as anything else I check seems to confirm that the swapfile is working as expected.
Aug 24 16:20:17 bumblebee kernel: PM: Cannot find swap device, try swapon -a
Aug 24 16:20:17 bumblebee kernel: PM: Cannot get swap writer
Aug 24 16:20:17 bumblebee kernel: PM: hibernation: Basic memory bitmaps freed

The swap exists, it does get used in general (confirmed via htop), and I've also remade the swapfile by running
> sudo swapoff /swapfile
> sudo mkswap /swapfile

  mkswap: /swapfile: warning: wiping old swap signature.
  Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 20 GiB (21474832384 bytes)
  no label, UUID=e82dd3b3-3ce2-44bf-be60-751294fa9323

> sudo swapon /swapfile
> sudo swapon --show

  NAME      TYPE SIZE USED PRIO
  /swapfile file  20G   0B   -2


Shutdown
Trigger - Problem appears when I shutdown via the OS gui or when run sudo shutdown now.
Expectation - Laptop should take a few seconds to turn off, the screen should turn black, then I should hear the audio tick, and I can put the laptop away. Later, I should press the power button to turn the laptop back on.
What actually happens - Laptop takes a few seconds to turn off, the screen turns off (not just black like in the suspend case, this time I think it's actually off), but I never heard the audio tick. Aside from that, the laptop appears to be off, but it actually is still on. I mainly notice because if I put it away in my sleeve, later I will find that it is very warm, clearly still on in some capacity. The laptop stays in this unresponsive state indefinitely until I power it off manually.
What I tried
Log of sudo journalctl -S today (cut from the moment I run pm-shutdown until the time I manually reboot): https://pastebin.com/5T3cLYM2
I couldn't find anything worth digging deeper, but I don't really know what I'm looking for.
What Now?
Obviously I'd love to be able to solve the issue as a whole, but I guess at this stage I'm generally lost on what I should check to try an diagnose it more fully, which logs I should pay attention to, and what to try.
Thank you to anyone who'd be willing to guide me in the right direction!
UPDATE 2024-08-26
I managed to make some progress; first of all, turns out my swap was misconfigured (see this comment) and that explained some of the issues with hibernate (though not all). Then, I managed tested out a previous kernel (see this comment) and that fixed hibernate, probably shutdown (it did get stuck once on the splash screen, but it worked twice), but not suspend.



kernel
suspend
hibernate
shutdown




6.8.0-40-generic
Screen goes black, fan stays on, power light stays on (but on slow pulse, which I believe is correct), system freezes, I have to manually power off.
Half works. Screen goes black, fan stays on, system freezes, I have to manually power off. But when I power back on, system wakes from hibernation as normal.
Screen goes black, keyboard backlight stays on, fan stays on, system freezes, I have to manually power off.


6.8.0-39-generic

Screen stays on (showing OS), fan stays on, system freezes, I have to manually power off. But when I power back on, system wakes from hibernation as normal.
Screen stays on (frozen on logoff splashscreen, fan stays on, system freezes, I have to manually power off.


6.5.0-35-generic
Screen goes black, power light stays on, fan stays on, system freezes, I have to manually power off.
Works.
Worked twice, but got frozen on logoff splashscreen once. Might have been an isolated case, I'll test some more.



Other Updates based on other threads I have found online about the failure of suspend, I also tried disabling wifi, ethernet, and bluetooth from the BIOS, and it changed nothing (on the 6.5.0-40 kernel)

Basically Suspend freezes; Hibernation is abandoned & powerdown works but laptop remains warm. For suspend see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1499938/kubuntu-22-04-wifi-freeze-after-hwe-kernel-upgrade-to-6-5-was-fine-on-6-2 which has a similar wi-fi freeze using the same device? Power off seems to work If the PC remains warm it suggests some sort of hardware fault. Is there anyway you can turn it off (power button?) so that the unit doesn't get warm? I assume not on charge A warm PC when it is off could suggest battery problems and possible safety hazard. Finally, did hibernation ever work?

re: suspend: I'll look more into the wifi freeze. didn't think the warning would be related.
re: hibernation: yes; I had not been using it in a very long time though, probably at least a year, but all of this was working as expected at one time or another (with suspend being the most obvious being used every day).
re: power off: yes, in all cases I can always just long-press the power button to make sure that the laptop just turns off.  The laptop being warm to me was just suggesting it being on in some capacity, for about an hour, inside a sleeve inside a backpack, and nothing more.

I've gone and done a deeper dive into the logs. I've used suspend 80+ times since the start of the month, and here's some examples of the respective logs.
logs from earlier in the month, all successful:

https://pastebin.com/rnWAzhd1
https://pastebin.com/gjhEZahp
https://pastebin.com/gdCX9R7h
https://pastebin.com/7ZfM41Uq
https://pastebin.com/EUbHiFkn
https://pastebin.com/G1NeKjLs

these are the last few cases where suspend worked:
-https://pastebin.com/WWNFJY03
-https://pastebin.com/6s1uZ5Tt
-https://pastebin.com/euf0xUqt
-https://pastebin.com/fV2xgtiN

then it stopped working from the next one, here's some examples:

https://pastebin.com/VM3UBWBd
https://pastebin.com/EUQ3Vz18
https://pastebin.com/Q2XunCcg
https://pastebin.com/B9BYfRTu
https://pastebin.com/3rLw2rAw

In each of these last cases the system stopped working until I booted. Quite consistently, the last message seems to be "PM: suspend entry (deep)", though that doesn't tell me much.
I was assuming all the problems of suspend, hibernate, and shutdown were related, but just in case they aren't I'd rather focus on the suspend since that's what I actually need.

How do the dates match up with a kernel update? What does 'grep -B 6 -A 5 -nH $(uname -r) /var/log/apt/history.log' - give in date terms? (It appears to go wrong on 22/08/24 from your data?

@david here's a pastebin with the history logs https://pastebin.com/c7UKEbvY the last upgrade was 6 days prior to the suspend issue manifesting.

Two things.

Ensure your system firmware is current. Version 1.50/1.16 is current:
https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-x-series-laptops/thinkpad-x260/downloads/ds105890

Configure a dedicated swap partition. Remove a dynamic swapfile if one is present.



I'll check the BIOS firmware, I'm assuming it is old because I've never updated it.
re: swap: neither suspend nor shutdown use swap, so I'm not sure why switching to a swap partition would matter. Is there an active reason to think swapfile vs swap partition might be relevant? bc swapfile is easier to manage and messing with partitions can be risky.

I'm currently running 1.49 BIOS, which is not actually that old. Is there any reason to think that might be actually related?

There is a bug with hibernation wrt swapfile space. See https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/08/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-21-10/ for details and how to defeat it.

Why to update the firmware: because manufacturers mainly or only test with Windows. Subtle power management bugs are exactly the sort of thing to crop up with Linux. Why a swap partition: the original post was about issues with hibernation. When a PC hibernates, the RAM image is stored in the swap partition.

@david I thought I had already done that, but I noticed that I did one of the steps wrong, so I tried again, and it half worked.  The laptop looks like it is going into hibernation, but the power led stays on and flashes at high frequency.  Nothing happens until I keep it pressed to shut the laptop off. BUT, the good news is that when I turn it on, it wakes from hibernation.  Here's the system logs: https://pastebin.com/yEBMDVpp
So it seems like hibernation in some capacity is fixed, and it was indeed a separate issue. But another issue still afflicts suspend, hibernation, and shutdown.

To be explicitly clear, hibernation now works with a swapfile, without having to change to swap partition, but there still seems to be another problem related to powering off that is probably what is afflicting at least hibernation and shutdown, if not suspend as well.

Observation: The last update for 22.04 was from 6.5 to 6.8.0.40 which is now close to 6.8.0.41 of 24.04. In the hibernation link the swapfile bug is only targeted at 24.04. However, the bug reports hibernation fails completely so probably not connected.

Observation: A similar problem has recently been fixed. See bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2076576 12/08/24 22.04 kernel 5.12.0.118 https://askubuntu.com/questions/1523274/systemd-sleep-failed-to-put-system-to-sleep-system-resumed-again-device-or-re

Trying out a previous kernel definitely helped a lot (though mine are not the same versions as in the linked bug).  See the updated post for more details. I'll keep on investigating kernel versions as well, though I could still use some help figuring things out.
